# How to display dynamically rotated angle correctly?

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, react-konva

Thank you in advance for paying attention to my problem.

I am using a library called `react-konva` for working with **canvas**.
My task was to build the angle between two lines and display it.
Now it works, not perfectly, but still... But I can't resolve the issue with displaying of angle.

[image: Angle displaying]

In the example above I can move the dots in any directions.
And I have to calculate the text rotation.

Here is my code

```js
<Group>
        <Arc
          x={x}
          y={y}
          clockwise={this.clockwise}
          outerRadius={30}
          innerRadius={30}
          angle={formattedAngle}
          stroke={colors.brandGreen}
          strokeWidth={strokeWidth}
          dash={[5, 5]}
          rotation={this.getArcRotation(angle)}
        />
        <Text
          x={x}
          y={y}
          offsetX={45}
          offsetY={45}
          text={this.displayAngle(formattedAngle)}
          rotation={this.getTextRotation(angle)}
        />
      </Group>
```

```js
  getTextRotation = angle => {
    let { dots } = this.props
    const radiansOffset = getVectorDirection(dots[0], dots[1])
    if (this.clockwise) {
      return 360 - Math.abs(angle)
    }

    const degreesAngle = radiansToDegrees(angle)
    const degreesOffset = radiansToDegrees(radiansOffset)

    return degreesOffset - degreesAngle
  }
```

I need to rotate some container for text but not rotating text.
So 112 should display in the same position but its text should not be rotated.

Hope I explained available.

Comment: You could calculate the position completely in code and not specify an angle in the markup. Something like `pos = (x, y) + offsetRadius * (cos(angle), sin(angle)) .

Comment: It doesn't work for me correctly

const textX = x + 45 * Math.cos(angle)
const textY = y + 45 * Math.sin(angle)

Comment: @NicoSchertler, your answer is correct. I put the wrong values in the formula. Thank you!